# How to circumvent this box-shadow + transform bug in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

The code below works well in every modern browser, except Mozilla Firefox. The expected behaviour is to see some black text on a blue background. However, **Firefox shows two white vertical lines around the text**. Is there a trick like adding `zoom:1`, `z-index:1` to make it work, without changing the current style? These two haven't helped. Changing `font-size`, or removing any of `float`, `transform`, `box-shadow` would help, but none of the current styles should be removed or modified.

nVidia GT 240M, Windows 10, Firefox 41.0.2, hardware acceleration: on

bug report: [bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215868](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215868)

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}
div {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 #FFF;
  float: left;
  font-size: 44px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jg874sr0/

Comment: I don't see nothing white on Firefox (40.0, Win7).

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which OS do you use? Graphic card? Do you have hardware acceleration and OMTC enabled?

Comment: Tested without hardware acceleration, and there are no white lines.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem on a clean profile, I suggest going to bugzilla.mozilla.org and report the bug, providing the graphics information from about:support

Comment: Should I publish a website in a case like this and let the users wait for the browser update, or rather find a workaround until it's fixed?

Comment: @TamásBolvári If the patch to fix the bug is low-risk, it might be uplifted, and thus affect less users. But to be safe I would try to find a workaround.